# Javascript and Css: Height does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working with a javascript custom scroller, and I am also swapping content in/out of that scroller and the only problem is when I toggle different content the height stays the same of the original div and wont adjust, and I cant figure out why.

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){
(function($) {
    $.fn.Fader = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $('.clickme').bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $( "#mediaswap div" ).fadeOut();
                $( "#mediaswap div" + $(this).attr('name') ).fadeIn();
            })
        });
    }
})(jQuery);


$(function() {
    $('#mediaswap').Fader();
});
});//]]>
```

Andy my CSS:

```
#media_scroll{position:absolute; margin:0; width:590px; height:334px;}
#media_scroll .customScrollBox{position:relative; height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
#media_scroll .customScrollBox .container{position:relative; width:565px; top:0; float:left;}
#media_scroll .customScrollBox .content{clear:both;}
#media_scroll .dragger_container{position:relative; background: url(images/assets/track-bkg.jpg) no-repeat; width:10px; height:324px; float:left; margin:10px 0 0 10px; cursor:pointer;}
#media_scroll .dragger{position:absolute; width:14px; height:22px; background: url(images/assets/dragger.gif) no-repeat; margin-left:-3px; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; cursor:pointer;}
#media_scroll .dragger_pressed{position:absolute; width:14px; height:22px; margin-left:-3px; overflow:hidden;}
```

The div 'content' is the div that has the different div's with different heights within it.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the fadeIn() even working? it looks like the selector is wrong

Comment: I think we need to see the html to understand what's happening.

Comment: Yea, even if selecting like that works, you don't have a space between `div` and the `attr('name')`, so it will run together.

Answer (score 1):

Just gonna take a stab at this one despite lack of code:

`.content` is only going to be able to size to 334px as you set that as the maximum `height` for `#media_scroll`. Try using either `min-height: 334px;` or `height: auto;` and see if that doesnt help. You could also use jquery to size `#media_scroll`.

Also, posting code, adding it to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) really helps us trouble shoot your problem.

Also, to Tyrsuis' point:

`$( "#mediaswap div" + $(this).attr('name') ).fadeIn();`

should probably be something more like:

`$( "#mediaswap div " + $(this).attr('name') ).fadeIn();`

But keep in mind that if `$(this).attr('name')` wont add a '.' or '#' to the selector.
So you may end up trying to call something like:

> $("#mediaswap div elementName")

instead of:

```
$("#mediaswap div #elementName")
```